# Can I make a class in Typescript that implements an interface, and it's still able to have decorators on it?

Tags: typescript, decorator

Can I make a class in Typescript that implements an interface, and it's still able to have decorators on it?

I have a class foo

```
@MyDecoratorA()
export default class Foo {
    @MyDecoratorB()
    public mySearchFunc(source: string, subString: string) {

        /*a lot of logic here*/
       return true;
    }
}
```

and I Have my interface

```
  interface SearchFunc {
    (source: string, subString: string): boolean;
  }
```

I can make functions that implements myInterface like this:

```
let mySearch: SearchFunc;
mySearch = function(source: string, subString: string) {
    let result = source.search(subString);
    return result > -1;
}
```

[typescript reference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html)

I am trying make method mySearchFunc of class 'Foo"  implemets the interface "myInterface", but without lose decorator

I will need this decorator in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace the declaration of the `mySearchFunc` method on the class `Foo` to a field-declaration, where the type of the field is the interface and assign the method implementation to this field:

```
interface SearchFunc {
  (source: string, subString: string): boolean;
}

@MyDecoratorA()
export default class Foo
{
    @MyDecoratorB()
    public mySearchFunc : SearchFunc = (source: string, subString: string) => {

        /*a lot of logic here*/
       return true;
    }
}


var foo = new Foo();
// You can use the field the same way as if it was declared as method
foo.mySearchFunc("a", "b");
```

Instead of the arrow function `() => {}` you can also use the `function` notation:

```
@MyDecoratorA()
export default class Foo
{
    @MyDecoratorB()
    public mySearchFunc : SearchFunc = function(source: string, subString: string) {

        /*a lot of logic here*/
       return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: @AlexSilva You're welcome. Feel free to upvote, if it helped ;-)

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to vote :(
when i get it, i will comeback here to upvote